# Representing a graph as two lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph-theory

I have a list like this:

```
[(1,1.0,0.0),(2,2.0,0.0),(3,2.0,1.0),(4,3.0,0.0),(5,3.0,1.0),(14,3.0,2.0),(6,4.0,0.0),(7,4.0,1.0),(13,4.0,2.0),(8,5.0,0.0),(9,5.0,1.0),(10,6.0,0.0),(11,6.0,1.0),(12,7.0,0.0)]
```

where the first element is a node ID, second is an *x*- and third a *y*-coordinate.

A second list represents

```
[(1,[2,3]),(2,[4,5]),(3,[14]),(4,[6]),(5,[7]),(14,[6,7,13]),(6,[8]),(7,[9]),(13,[]),(8,[10]),(9,[11]),(10,[12]),(11,[12]),(12,[13])]`
```

where first element is the ID of this node, and the associated list contains successors of each node.

I want to write a function which takes a node ID, returns the corresponding *x*, *y* of both the node itself and its successors.  for example: Node 1 yields

> [(1.0,0.0,2.0,0.0),(1.0,0.0,2.0,1.0)]

because Node 1 has successors 2(2.0,0.0) and 3(2.0,1.0)

EDIT:

I wrote functions :

```
pairs [] = []
pairs ((nodeId,nodesucc):xs) =  map (nodeId,) nodesucc : pairs xs

pairsConcat = concat $ pairs $ edg graph2
```

so now second list looks like:

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,14),(4,6),(5,7),(14,6),(14,7),(14,13),(6,8),(7,9),(8,10),(9,11),(10,12),(11,12),(12,13)]
```

how to create tuple with 4 elements?

Comment: what did you try.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it

Comment: why do you want to do it

Comment: If you have literally no idea how to do this then first read a couple of Haskell tutorials / books.

Comment: leftaroundabout, i think there was another example and you didnt translate it into readable

Answer (score 1):

I second the comment above that you should try to read more, but in case an example of how this problem might be solved would still be useful:

This isn't directly related to your problem, but in general I would start by suggesting that you use a newtype for your node IDs and positions:

```
newtype Id = ID Int deriving (Eq, Ord)
data Point = Point Int Int
```

I would also suggest using a `Data.Map` to store this data, instead of an association list:

```
neighbors :: Map Id [Id]
points :: Map Id Point
```

Then this is a simple solution that decomposes this into (1) get the neighboring points and (2) adding this point to all of them.  This uses the `Maybe` monad to make composing things that might fail very nice and clean:

```
neighborPoints :: Id -> Maybe [Point]
neighborPoints id = lookup id neighbors >>= sequence . map (flip lookup points)

neighborPointsWithThisPoint :: Id -> Maybe [(Point, Point)]
neighborPointsWithThisPoint id = do
  p <- lookup points id
  ps <- neighborPoints id
  pure $ zip (repeat p) ps
```